# @Transactional in Spring Data Neo4j 6

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a simple Spring Boot project with Neo4j SDN (v6.1.1). The problem is that when I mark a method with @Transactional, it seems that it does not consider that (as opposed to when I used Neo4j-OGM and a previous version of SDN). When I checked the database after "template.save", the update was visible in the database, even before the whole method is run. What should I do?

The method:

```
@Transactional
void method() {
        template.deleteAll(Person.class);
        template.deleteAll(Club.class);
        // save by Neo4jTemplate
        Person person_1 = template.save(new Person("Reza", "Mahdavi", 22, new Member(new Club("Iran"), "2021")));
        // Save by Repository
        Person person_2 = repository.save(new Person("Ali" + new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(), "Alavi", 20, new Member(new Club("Iran"), "2020")));
        // Query by Repository
        Person ali = repository.findByName("Ali");
        // Query by Neo4jTemplate
        Optional<Person> reza = template.findById(person_1.getId(), Person.class);
        // Custom query
        Result result = driver.session().run("Match(n) return count(n) as count", TransactionConfig.builder().build());
        System.out.println("Entity Count: " + result.single().values().get(0));
}
```

Also, I have such sentences in logs:

> No need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleNeo4jRepository.toString]: This method is not transactional.

Code [here](https://github.com/shayantabrizi/sample-code-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method needs to have a *public* visibility. Otherwise Spring cannot create the needed infrastructure around this (proxy related).

There is a little bit more information around this in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations
A few lines under the linked section there is a box

> When you use proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
> only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
> private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
> no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
> configured transactional settings. If you need to annotate non-public
> methods, consider using AspectJ (described later).